# better view of my form

Tags: css

I have created a form on php.i would like this form to appear in the center of the screen but i dont know css very well.this is the css code i have created:

```
body{ font:100% normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:#161712;}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:auto;
}

th {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:18px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #161712;
    border-top:1px solid #161712; 
}
h2{
        text-align:center;
        color:#CC0000;}


table {
    color:#bbb;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 150%;
    padding:30px;
    border-bottom:#505050  thin solid;

}
.tr_caption {
    font-weight: bold;
}

form {
    width:400px;
}
input {
    padding:10px 10px;
    width:200px;
    background:#262626;
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom: 1px double #171717;
    border-top: 1px double #171717;
    border-left:1px double #333;
    border-right:1px double #333;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:right;
    background:#CC0000;
    border:0px;

    top:10px;
    left:482px;
    width:100px;
    bottom:50px;

    border-bottom: 1px double #660000;
    border-top: 1px double #660000;
    border-left:1px double #FF0033;
    border-right:1px double #FF0033;
}
.button:hover {
    background:#580000;
    border:0px;
    color:#FFF5CC;
}
```

Also, I'm attaching a photo of the view of my screen:
[image]

```
<body>  

<h2>Φόρμα συμπλήρωσης στοιχείων</h2>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))

        if (checkForm() == "")
        {
        makeXML(); 
        sendXML();
        }
        else echo "<font color='blue'>".checkform()."</font><br/><br/>";
?>


<form method="post">
    <table width="500px" >
        <tr><th colspan="2" >Στοιχεία του Πελάτη</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Όνοματεπώνυμο</td> <td><input type="text" name="custName" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["custName"];?>"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>E-mail</td> <td><input type="text" name="custMail" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["custMail"];?>"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Διεύθυνση</td> <td><input type="text" name="custAddress" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["custAddress"];?>"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Τηλέφωνο</td> <td><input type="text" name="custPhone" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["custPhone"];?>"> </td></tr>
    </table>
    <br/>

    <table width="500px">
        <tr><th colspan="2" align="center">Στοιχεία της Παραγγελίας</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Προϊόν</td> <td><input type="text" name="prodName" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["prodName"];?>"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Αριθμός Προϊόντων</td> <td><input type="text" name="numOfProd" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["numOfProd"];?>"> </td></tr>


    </table>
    <br/>

    <table width="500px">
        <tr><th colspan="2" align="center">Στοιχεία του Προμηθευτή</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Επωνυμία</td> <td><input type="text" name="suplName" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["suplName"];?>"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Διεύθυνση</td> <td><input type="text" name="suplAddress" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["suplAddress"];?>"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email</td> <td><input type="text" name="suplMail" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["suplMail"];?>"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Τηλέφωνο</td> <td><input type="text" name="suplPhone" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["suplPhone"];?>"> </td></tr>
    </table>
    <br/>

    <table width="500px">
        <tr><th colspan="2" align="center">Στοιχεία Μεταφορικής Εταιρείας</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Επωνυμία</td> <td><input type="text" name="carrierName" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["carrierName"];?>"> </td></tr>

        <tr><td>Διεύθυνση</td> <td><input type="text" name="carrierAddress" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["carrierAddress"];?>"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email</td> <td><input type="text" name="carrierMail" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["carrierMail"];?>"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Τηλέφωνο</td> <td><input type="text" name="carrierPhone" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST["carrierPhone"];?>"> </td></tr>
    </table>
    <br/>


            <input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="<?php echo time(); ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Αποστολή" /> 
            <input type="reset" name="reset" class="button" value="Επαναφορά"/>  


</form>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</body>
```

Comment: i would like the 4 tables i have created to be in the center of the screen and no at the center-left...Sorry if this is no understandable!

Comment: _menu : hard to answer without the html

Comment: @pastjean:i re-edited my question and i have added the html code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is usually done

```
<body>
 <div class="used-tocenter">
     content...
 </div>
</body>
```

then in the CSS you text-align:center the first div and text-align:left the other one.

The other way is to margin:0 auto the body. and put a width to the containing div

```
body{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
div{ 
    text-align:left;
    width:500px;
}
```

There is another way :

```
position:absolute
left:50%;
width:500px; 
margin-left:-250px; /*half of width */
```

Comment: i'm not sure if it well explained, this is from my mind only, i'm going to check my code to confirm!

Comment: i have tried the way with the div classes,it s working but i have a little problem.As you can see in the photo i have the form and at the end of the form there are two red button.i create two div classes,one for the form and one for the buttons,but the buttons are not exactly in the center of the screen..any idea?

Comment: also,i would like the button to be side by side but unfortunately they are one on the top of the other..:(

Comment: sorry , not a pro with html/css and its quirks.

Comment: i just found my wrong.i should add float:right; on a btn in order to be side by side!thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Try sticking everything within a  tag with the attribute style="text-align:center".

Also, I would give each label in your tables (the left-most column) a new class that specifies the width. That way, your entry boxes would line up.

Comment: i think that text-align will also move my text to the center of the screen...i would like to move the hole table.You think that this can work?(tnx for your answer by the way!!:))